# Oracle sql query rewrite

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to query data in the database, have the following table

```
COLUMNS:  Type, Location, name, etc.

DATA:
 1. Stores in NJ, name = xyz
 2. Restaurants in NY
 3. Hotels in US
 4. Stores in PA
 5. Restaurants in VA
 6. Hotels in MD
 7. Stores in NJ, name = abc
 8. etc.
```

I need a query, to fetch the data from 1, 2, 3

Right now, I have the following query.  This runs faster.  But is there any other query I can use without UNION

```
select type, location from table1 
where type='stores' and location='NJ' and name='XYZ'
  UNION
select type, location from table1 
where type='restaurants' and location='NY'
  UNION
select type, location from table1 
where type='hotels' and location='US'
```

Comment: Don't use `union` in a situation like this. It will try to do a `distinct`, which means that you're unnecessarily de-duplicating.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OR:

```
select type, location from table1 
where (type='stores' and location='NJ' and name='XYZ')
or (type='restaurants' and location='NY')
or (type='hotels' and location='US');
```

Comment: thanks Andrew for your answer.  I tried this, it is taking considerable time compared to my previous query.  My table contains huge amounts of data.

Comment: Do your tables have accurate (enough) statistics?

Answer (score 1):

`UNION ALL` is faster then using `OR` and prolly is what you really need:

```
select type, location from table1 
where type='stores' and location='NJ' and name='XYZ'
  UNION ALL
select type, location from table1 
where type='restaurants' and location='NY'
  UNION ALL
select type, location from table1 
where type='hotels' and location='US'
```

If you really want the `OR`:

```
select type, location from table1 
where (type='stores' and location='NJ' and name='XYZ')
or (type='restaurants' and location='NY')
or (type='hotels' and location='US');
```

---

To make your query faster, create indexes on `type`, `location` and `name` columns!

Comment: ya, tried OR, but my query is very slow now.  Is there anything I can use such as scalar subquery etc.  If so, what will the syntax be for that.

Comment: To make it faster create indexes on type, location and name columns!

Comment: Thanks aF.  I created index as suggested by you. Still no luck.

Comment: @user12121 - it would help to know what indexes you have on TABLE1, how up-to-date the statistics are, how many rows you have in the table, how many rows exist for each of the conditions you're querying, the rewritten query you're using, and the plan Oracle generates for the rewritten query.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  I looked at the query plan and I saw where the problem is coming from.